# remove duplicate from list in object c#

Tags: c#, distinct

I'm desperately trying to delete all the items with a list of the same value inside.

Here's the code:

```
    private void Button_deleteDouble_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        boardGenerate.Add(new BoardInformation(146, new List<string> { "test" }));
        boardGenerate.Add(new BoardInformation(545, new List<string> { "test" }));

        boardGenerate = boardGenerate.DistinctBy(x => x.positionQueen).ToList();
    }
```

Normally, since the two lists inside the object are the same, the .DistinctBy() command should remove one of the two objects.

But no, my object list still has the same two objects with the same list

.positionQueen is the name of the variable containing the list

Could somebody help me?

**Edit :**

The **DistinctBy()** method comes from **MoreLinq**.

And this is my BoardInformation class:

```
public class BoardInformation
{
    public BoardInformation(int nbQueen, List<string> positionQueen)
    {
        this.nbQueen = nbQueen;
        this.positionQueen = positionQueen;
    }

    public int nbQueen { get; set; }
    public List<string> positionQueen { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help that we don't know anything about `BoardInformation`. Please provide a [mcve]. But note that `List<T>` doesn't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode`. If `positionQueen` is the `List<string>`, you probably need to provide an `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>` to the `DistinctBy` call. (It would also help if you'd say which `DistinctBy` method this is - is it MoreLINQ?)

Comment: I did an edit. I don't understand what you mean by Equal and GetHashCode at all, can you explain it better?

Comment: You're adding 2 things and then selecting using `Distinct`, why would it delete?

Comment: Anyway, I put a different value for the demonstration, but normally both objects should have exactly the same first value.

Comment: You have two lists. They have equal content, but try printing out `boardGenerate[0].positionQueen.Equals(boardGenerate[1].positionQueen)` and it will print False, because `List<T>` doesn't override `Equals` - and that's what `DistinctBy` uses to find equal values.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend starting to follow [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 3):

Set-based operations like `Distinct` and `DistinctBy` need a way of determining whether two values are the same. You're using `DistinctBy`, so you're already asking MoreLINQ to compare the "inner lists" for equality - but you're not saying how to do that.

`List<T>` doesn't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, which means it inherits the *reference equality* behaviour from `System.Object`. In other words, if you create two separate `List<T>` objects, they won't compare as equal, even if they have the same content. For example:

```cs
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
Console.WriteLine(list1.Equals(list2)); // False
```

You need to tell `DistinctBy` how you want to compare the two lists, using an `IEqualityComparer<T>` - where `T` in this case is `List<string>` (because that's the type of `BoardInformation.positionQueen`.

Here's an example of a generic `ListEqualityComparer` you could use:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public sealed class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<T> elementComparer;

    public ListEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> elementComparer) =>
        this.elementComparer = elementComparer;

    public ListEqualityComparer() : this(EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y) =>
        ReferenceEquals(x, y) ? true
        : x is null || y is null ? false
        // Delegate to LINQ's SequenceEqual method
        : x.SequenceEqual(y, elementComparer);

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
    {
        if (obj is null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        // Just a very simple hash implementation
        int hash = 23;
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 +
                (item is null ? 0
                 : elementComparer.GetHashCode(item));
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

You'd then pass that to `DistinctBy`, like this:

```cs
// We're fine to use the default *element* comparer (string.Equals etc)
var comparer = new ListEqualityComparer<string>();
boardGenerate = boardGenerate.DistinctBy(x => x.positionQueen, comparer).ToList();
```

Now `DistinctBy` will call into the comparer, passing in the lists, and will consider your two `BoardInformation` objects are equal - so only the first will be yielded by `DistinctBy`, and you'll end up with a list containing a single item.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to whether a equality check is using referential equality or value equality...you want value equality based on a specific property and that has to be done by hand.

When there is no `IEqualityComparer` provided which can used to compare individual objects (*which is need by the `Distinct` call*), the system determines the equality from each item's *references* by using their derived `object` low level service method call of `GetHashCode` from each reference; hence a reference difference is done and all your values in the list are unique (*not equal*) regardless of similar property values.

What you are looking for is to have **value equality** checked specifically for the `nbQueenProperty`.

---

To fully utilize `Distinct` one must create a `IEqualityComparer` and modify the `GetHashCode`. By specifing the hash value which can make objects equal...you can weed out the same `positionQueen` (*or other properties*) instances out.

**Example**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int nbQueen { get; set; }
}
```

Equality comparer to weed out all nbQueen similarities:

```
class ContactEmailComparer : IEqualityComparer < MyClass >
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
      return x.nbQueen.Equals(y.nbQueen); // Compares by calling each `GetHashCode` 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass obj)
    {
        return obj.nbQueen.GetHashCode(); // Add or remove other properties as needed.
    }
}
```

Test code

```
var original = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass() { nbQueen = 1, Name="Alpha"   },
    new MyClass() { nbQueen = 1, Name="Omega" },
    new MyClass() { nbQueen = 3, Name="Delta" }

};

IEqualityComparer<MyClass> comparer = new ContactEmailComparer();

var newOne = original.Distinct( comparer ).ToList();
```

Result of the value of `newOne` :

[image]

---

To be clear...

> ... .DistinctBy() command should remove one of the two objects.

Does not remove anything. It returns a **reference to a new list** that should be distinct via the equality operation. The original list (the reference to it) does not change.

Comment: "it compares by reference values" - well, it calls Equals/GetHashCode, which *by default* uses reference identity for equality. But if the type itself overrides Equals/GetHashCode, that's a different matter. I think the first paragraph could be clarified.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough. Updated first section to differentiate between reference equality operation done by default (which uses `GetHashCode` off of `Object`) against the perceived *value equality* the user desires.

Comment: Well it uses `Equals` as well as `GetHashCode` - an implementation which doesn't use `Equals` can't be correct. I have to say that if I didn't already know what was going on, I'd find it hard to follow your explanation - and in particular, you seem to be *assuming* the OP wants equality in terms of `nbQueen`, but there's no indication that that's what they actually want to do. Indeed, they specifically say they want to compare the lists. If the OP really did just want to compare by `nbQueen`, they could use `boardGenerate.DistinctBy(x => x.nbQueen)` - no custom comparers involved at all.

Comment: At minimum I've given the OP a guide on how to use `Distinct` ...which hopefully answers the question in the short term.  I base the request by the OP mentioning that that `boardGenerate = boardGenerate.DistinctBy(x => x.positionQueen).ToList();` which the OP claims does not work (for the situation?) : "But no, my object list still has the same two objects with the same list"

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work *because `List<T>` uses reference equality by default*. Providing an `IEqualityComparer<List<T>>` as a second argument to `DistinctBy` would work fine. I don't see why you would assume that the OP is using entirely the wrong property. The example they've given doesn't even use the same value for `nbQueen` for both values, so your code would give the same result (considering the two objects to be unequal, when the OP wants to consider them as equal).

Answer (score 0):

**LINQ solution**

because you have another List inside your class you can not use District or DistrictBy, alternatively, you can use LINQ to filter the list.

```cs
     boardGenerate = (from b in boardGenerate
                      from l in b.positionQueen
                      group new { l,b } by l into g
                      select g.First().b
                      ).ToList();
   // this returns just first duplicate item like district
```